# How to remove a white block space on the right of a textarea in FF?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I would like a textarea to display the same text as a div element of the same width, and it works fine in Chrome, but Firefox has a white block to the right of a textarea that chops off the last letter.

You can find a jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ngn6Y/9/
which contains the same code as below:

```
var fontsize = '12px';
$(function(){
    var t = 'abcdefg';
    var e = $('body');
    var a = $('<div>').appendTo(e).text(t)
        .css({
            border:'thin solid black',
            position:'absolute',
            top:'40px',
            padding:'2px',
            margin:0,
            height:fontsize,
            'font-size':fontsize,
            'font-family': '"lucida grande",Tahoma, Arial,sans-serif'
        });
    var b = $('<textarea>').appendTo(e).val(t)
        .css({
            border:'thin solid black',
            padding:'2px',
            margin:0,
            outline:0,
            resize:'none',
            overflow:'hidden',
            height:fontsize,
            'word-wrap':'break-word',
            'font-size':fontsize,
            'font-family': '"lucida grande",Tahoma, Arial,sans-serif'
        }).width(a.width());
});
```

Thanks!

Edit: thanks to an answer by Ionuț G. Stan below I added another qualification to the question: this textarea needs to wrap on break-word e.g. with 'word-wrap':'break-word', otherwise the whole point of text-shadowing gets lost when a word is longer than the maximum width allowed.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to apply CSS?

Comment: sorry, it seemed a bit easier to copy paste just one type of code

Comment: after fiddling with it more i see that adding 3 pixels to width makes it work, like this .width(a.width() + 3). But I'm hoping to make a font-size independant plugin and I'd like to find a way to determine this value for all browsers at any font size.

Answer (score 1):

Add `word-wrap: normal` to the textarea. Seems to fix the problem in FF 4.0.1.

Comment: wow - works in 3.6 too, how strange. It does not fix with "word-wrap:break-word;" which is what's needed in a text-shadow situation like this. I should edit it into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox gives the textarea an extra 0px 1px padding for compatibility with Internet Explorer.